# Canonical form of PDE (2nd order) and its general solution.

Tags: partial-differential-equations, wave-equation, hyperbolic-equations, linear-pde

The PDE is given is:
$$ 4u_{xx} + 5u_{xy} + u_{yy} + u_x + u_y = 2$$
I need to reduce this hyperbolic equation into a canonical form.
I got the characteristics as $\xi = y-x$ and $\eta = y - \frac{x}{4}$

Let $w(\xi,\eta) = u(x(\xi,\eta),y(\xi,\eta)) $. After substituting the partial derivatives of $u$ as pd's of $w$, I worked out the canonical form as (if anyone can confirm my answer it would be reassuring)
$$ w_{\xi\eta} - \frac{w_{\eta}}{3} = -\frac{8}{9}$$
How to solve this PDE to obtain the general solution? 
I proceeded in the following way: $v = w_{\eta}$, which gives
$$v_{\eta} - \frac{v}{3} = -\frac{8}{9} $$
And solving this equation I got
$$  w(\xi,\eta) = \int 3e^{(\xi + g(\eta))/3} \ \partial \eta + \frac{8}{3}\eta + C$$
or 
$$u(x,y) = \boxed{ C + \frac{8}{3}\left(y-\frac{1}{4}x \right) + \int 3e^{(y-x + g(y-x/4))/3} \ (\partial y - \frac{1}{4}\partial x) } $$
I am not sure about the result. It looks messy and I don't know if my approach is correct. Any input is appreciated. Thanks in advance.